# django-admin.py startproject is not working

Tags: python, django, windows-xp

after installing django I tried `django-admin.py startproject mysite` and that worked, then I got a simple site working and I wanted to start on something real, so I tried `django-admin.py startproject newsite` and nothing happened. Whenever I try the command nothing happens now.. any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

For anyone stumbling across this now, this problem is a result of Windows not obeying the #!C:\Path\To\Virtualenv\Scripts\Python.exe hashbang at the top of django-admin.py, and therefore running it with the wrong python.exe (evidently a virtualenv bug).

However, with virtualenv active, you can use the following command, which will result in the correct python being used, and everything being ok:

```
python C:\Path\To\Virtualenv\Scripts\django-admin.py startproject <project_name>
```

Comment: or python C:\Python27\Scripts\django-admin.py startproject <projectname> works without using virtualenv - Thanks!

Comment: The answer is so simple, yet somehow I missed it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can as well copy django-admin.py to your working directory.

Answer (score 10):

**If you are running Windows for a quick fix you can create a batch file with the following values:**

```
@echo off
@echo "Enter Proyect name"
set /p proj_name=
set building="Building django project %proj_name%"
@echo %building%
python c:/Python27/Scripts/django-admin.py startproject %proj_name%
pause
```

**I named the file "django.bat" and to use it you can just simply add a copy in the directory you want to start the project, execute the file and it will ask you for a project name, provide one and then Voila!!**

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks your django.bat is indeed helpful before this i was getting error as 
ImportError: Could not import settings 'mysite.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is
there an import error in the settings file?): No module named 'mysite'
but batch file help me to solve my problem... Thanks once again

Answer (score 7):

Do you have a `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable set (presumably from the `mysite` project)?  If so, django thinks you're working on the old project and doesn't give you the `startproject` option.  Try unsetting the environment variable and trying again.

Comment: "Do you have a DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable set?" how do I check this?

Comment: @Erik: On unix: `echo $DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` and on windows: `echo %DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE%` at the command line.

Comment: echo %DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE% just returns %DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE%

Comment: OK, so the variable isn't set.  Have you tried executing django-admin startproject again?  Same problem?

Comment: ya same problem, it appears that notepad++ is opening django-admin.py whenever I run `django-admin.py startproject something`..

Comment: @erikvold You probably have set that *.py files are opened by notepad++ by default. You should try to change default opening to python. (properties-> open with...)

Comment: Clearing an old `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` worked for me. For balance; windows clear is `>set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=` applying nothing after the `=`

Answer (score 6):

For me worked without `.py` extension, since there was `.exe` by that name in my windows:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts\django-admin startproject HelloWorld
```

Answer (score 5):

Try for this commond:

> `django-admin startproject mysite`

instead of django-admin.py startproject mysite.

Comment: that solved it!

Comment: Works! for 2022 in windows 11 for Django 3 LTS!

Answer (score 3):

If everything is installed properly, when you open the command prompt, 
navigate to the desktop folder with

```
cd C:\Users\YOURNAME\Desktop
```

then type

```
django-admin startproject YOURPROJECTNAME
```

The project should appear on your desktop.

If you didn't navigate to your desktop folder and run the command there, your project could be placed in the `windows\system32` folder on the C drive.

Comment: Thanks, my issue was on windows you don't use .py

Comment: I used `django-admin startproject YOURPROJECTNAME .` ... note the trailing dot at the end. This prefents the nested folder structure.

Answer (score 1):

Go on to c:/python**/Scripts/ you must find `django-admin.py` there that fixes your problem use the absolute path.

Comment: Yes, using absolute path works, but simply using the relative path does not work, even though the path to python scripts + path to django/bin are added to environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead! It also works inside `virtualenv`

```
python "C:\Python27\Scripts\django-admin.py" startproject test2
```

Answer (score 1):

after years I have to answer this question because the answer is changed for WINDOWS now

```
python C:\Path\To\Virtualenv\Scripts\django-admin.exe startproject <project_name>
```

you can use .exe for windows in Scripts folder

Comment: Currently it is as in the answer above. It is worth adding that you do not need to be in the directory, e.g. D:\python_projects\my_project\env\Scripts. You can enter it in the directory D:\python_projects\my_project and it also works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

**1)** Select a `.py` file and right click and select `Open with...`
**2)** Here select `Python Launcher for Windows`

*This solution is provided  for Windows OS*

Answer (score 0):

I'm on a Mac and had a similar problem after installing with pip3. I reinstalled and it corrected the error. You can try going to the #django irc channel at irc.freenodes

Answer (score 0):

Try out this way.

1> Look where your python is installed if cannot find it in C:/ Python().

```
$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84297, Aug 24 2010, 18:13:38) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'c:\\Python26\\python.exe'
>>> sys.exec_prefix
'c:\\Python26'
>>>
>>> print '\n'.join(sys.path)

c:\Python26\lib\site-packages\setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg
c:\Python26\lib\site-packages\nose-1.0.0-py2.6.egg
C:\Windows\system32\python26.zip
c:\Python26\DLLs
c:\Python26\lib
c:\Python26\lib\plat-win
c:\Python26\lib\lib-tk
c:\Python26
c:\Python26\lib\site-packages
c:\Python26\lib\site-packages\win32
c:\Python26\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
c:\Python26\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
c:\Python26\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode
```

2> After that move into Scripts folder. There you may find django-admin.py. Now copy full path of that file.

3>Now run this command

python *path of the file* startproject *name of Project*

eg.
    python C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts\django-admin.py startproject mysite

hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Even I faced the same problem. I even tried adding the directory to Environmental variables but it was not working, so I had to use `python -m django` for it, but it didn't satisfy me, so I did a tricky thing.

Instead of adding the directory to Environmental variables, I copied the installed package and pasted it to the first directory (*default directory*) in environmental variable and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

I have a easy solution for this. normally download the django-admin file from the web the add it to the python\script folder then add the `C:\python\script` to the environment variable then try the command i.e django-admin startproject

Answer (score 0):

If you have pip installed in that environment you can always download the Django in the virtual environment and use it to start your project like I did instead of downloading it from web or changing environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

My project made the ".py" file into a ".exe" file. So instead of:
"django-admin.py startproject"

I needed to do

```
> django-admin.exe startproject
```

It worked for me.