# django-admin startproject not working as intended

Tags: python, django

I am going through a Django tutorial and I tried to use `django-admin startproject NAME` to create project folders. 
According to the tutorial, I should get the following after typing that in:

```
NAME/
    __init__.py
    manage.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
```

I typed that in Powershell. No error message came out but it did not create anything in the current directory.
What am I doing wrong? I am working on Vista x32 with Python 2.7. And I have Django 1.4.2 installed. I also have
the `C:/Python27` under environment variables.

Comment: please add output of: django-admin --version

Comment: @fsw A black screen quickly popped out and disappeared. Then nothing happended. No error messages when I typed in that command.

Comment: Can you import django from the python shell?

Comment: Should have printed django version. Seems like a problem with Powershell and not Django. have you tried this: http://www.thebitguru.com/blog/view/244-Running%20django-admin%20in%20PowerShell

Comment: possible duplicate of [django-admin.py startproject is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681216/django-admin-py-startproject-is-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `python C:\Python27\Scripts\django-admin.py startproject NAME` without having to go through virtualenc.

Here's the link I got this:

[django-admin.py startproject is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681216/django-admin-py-startproject-is-not-working)