# Django-admin startproject permanent fix?

Tags: python, django, cmd

I just installed Django yesterday and went through part 1 and 2 of the tutorial no problems. Things were fuzzy so I wanted to start again. Between last night and now, only difference is I got Windows 10.

I type into command: django-admin startproject mysite2

It shows no errors, but it does not pop mysite2 or anything into the directory I am in. After searching an hour or so, I find a solution in 
[django-admin.py startproject is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681216/django-admin-py-startproject-is-not-working)

If I type into cmd: python C:\Python27\Scripts\django-admin.py startproject , it works. However, it's going to get a bit tedious and I can't help but think this problem is going to extend further down the line too. What is the reason why I can only start the project this way, and is there a way I can permanently change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like when you upgraded, the PATH environment variable was modified. If that's the case, here's how you can fix it.

**Why can I only start the project this way?**

When the operating system sees the `django-admin` command, it does not know what that means. It checks the `PATH` variable (which holds a list of directories as a single string). The OS will then check each of these directories for a program named `django-admin`. It appears that during the course of the upgrade the path variable was modified and now no longer includes `C:\Python27\Scripts`.

**Is there a way to permanently change it?**

Yes. You'll just need the add `C:\Python27\Scripts` to your `PATH`. [This page](https://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml) explains how to update `PATH` for Windows 8 (though at the top it also says it is applicable to Windows 10). Specifically:

> Windows 8
>
> 1) Drag the Mouse pointer to the Right bottom corner of the screen
>
> 2) Click on the Search icon and type: Control Panel
>
> 3) Click on -> Control Panel -> System -> Advanced
>
> 4) Click on Environment Variables, under System Variables, find PATH, and click on it.
>
> 5) In the Edit windows, modify PATH by adding the location of the class to the value for PATH. If you do not have the item PATH, you may
>   select to add a new variable and add PATH as the name and the location
>   of the class as the value.
>
> 6) Close the window.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you reinstall python and django.