# django-admin.py: No module named deltatest.settings

Tags: python, django-admin

I am new to Django.
I have built some project with `django-admin.py` before, but suddenly it doesn't work anymore.
When I try to run `django-admin.py`, there is an error `"ImportError: No module named deltatest.settings".`
I unstalled and reinstalled django but it also show those mistake.
Would you help me to find out the problem?
Thank you very much!

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681216/django-admin-py-startproject-is-not-working

Comment: Thank you. When I input “echo %DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE%”, it reply  "deltatest.settings". I think there is  something wrong in environment variable set.