# 'startproject' command not working with virtualenv, but working without it

Tags: python, django, django-admin, virtualenv

Django is unable to create a new project folder when I code after activating virtualenv (namely myDjangoEnv):

```
django-admin.py startproject myproject
```

The error displayed is:

```
Unable to create process using 'C:/Users/Shreyas Jain/Miniconda3/envs/myDjangoEnv\python.exe "C:\Users\Shreyas Jain\Miniconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\django-admin.py"  startproject myproject'
```

When I tried the same command without activating the virtualenv, django created a project folder without any error.

This problem is occurring from past 2-3 days and I am still unable to fix this issue.
Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Before asking this question, I've tried to google it a lot. I read so many community answers on various communities and also I read a lot on StackOverflow. But unfortunately, nothing helped me.

Comment: this didn't work? https://stackoverflow.com/a/5601612/4186008

Comment: have you tried `python -m django startproject <project name>`?

Comment: @AmanGarg unfortunately not. The error shown is: "python: can't open file 'C:\Users\Shreyas': [Errno 2] No such file or directory."

Comment: @Josh21 Yes. It worked for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Josh21 But can you tell me why it is not working with django-admin?

Comment: @ShreyasJain will post it as an answer then; click the check in the answer if it helps you.

Comment: @Josh21 Can you tell me why it is not working with django-admin? Because some days ago, I was able to do this using django-admin.

Comment: @ShreyasJain, I don't know why `django-admin.py` does not work as I am using `python -m django startproject <project name>` whenever I create new projects, and did not bother using other options, since its working fine. You may check the answer to know that this question has been resolved (at least you are able to start new project)

Answer (score -1):

Try `python -m django startproject <project name>` to create new project.